# how to use CheckBoxes to select images in visual c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, checkbox

According to codes below, I can gather my stored images from my SQL server table and put a CheckBox under each of them.My aim is to use these CheckBoxes to select images above them and take an action with another user control (i.e. button for erasing them from DB or copying them to another directory).I tried to create an event handler but cannot achieve with my level of c# knowledge. I kindly ask for a solution and guidance for better understanding.

```
  private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox[] pba = new PictureBox[100];
        SqlConnection con4 = new SqlConnection(DBHandler.GetConnectionString());
        SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("ReadAllImage", con4);
        cmd4.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd4);
        DataSet dt2 = new DataSet("ImageData");
        da2.SelectCommand = cmd4;
        da2.Fill(dt2);
        int a = comboBox1.Items.Count;
        byte[] xdata = new byte[0];
        CheckBox[] chckbx = new CheckBox[400];
        for (var i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            DataRow myRow2 = null;
            if (myRow2 == null)
            {
                myRow2 = dt2.Tables[0].Rows[i];
                xdata = (byte[])myRow2["ImageData"];

                MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream(xdata);

                PictureBox npb = new PictureBox();
                npb.Size = new Size(60, 60);
                int b = i / 5;
                npb.Location = new Point(420 + (i % 5) * 70, 20 + (90 * b));
                npb.Image = Image.FromStream(stream2);
                npb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pba[i] = npb;

                this.Controls.Add(pba[i]);

                CheckBox chckbxx = new CheckBox();
                chckbxx.Location = new Point(420 + (i % 5) * 70, 80 + (90 * b));
                chckbxx.AutoSize = true;
                chckbx[i] = chckbxx;
                this.Controls.Add(chckbx[i]);

            }
```

[image] 
my example output after running the codes.I wanna use the chekckboxes like in this pic.I actually managed to create them like this but couldn't make them related with images above them.

Comment: A simple but not elegant way would be to not add the Checkboxes and PictureBoxes to `this.Controls` only, but also to custom `List<CheckBox>` and `List<PictureBox>`, which you define in the background, and then, when a Checkbox is ticked, get `IndexOf(yourCheckbox)` from the `List<CheckBox>` and access the `List<PictureBox>` with that index. Another possibility would be to use the `CheckBox.Tag` property and assign the PictureBox to it, so you can get the relation... whatever for you need it wherever in your code.

Comment: _Checkbox has no Tag property_ Yes it has as every control does.

Comment: Looking at your image sizes I would use a Checked ListView and an ImageList.

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh I am working on your suggestion now. If I achieve I will post the solution (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

make a custom control holding the image AND the checkbox.
then both are always connected:
logically and programmatically.

samples for custom controls : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723977%28v=expression.40%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2016/Writing-your-Custom-Control-step-by-step

Comment: I am not sure if I am able to handle custom controls with such a limited knowledge :(

Comment: then try that (like  LInsoDeTeh mentioned) :      
     chckbxx.Tag = npb;
     PictureBox p = (PictureBox)chckbxx.Tag;

Comment: the real problem is creating them dynamically so I cannot specify the checkboxes when created.I tried to add a button to take checkbox ids to match them with picture box ids but I could not retrieve anything because of the closed for loop that I am using for generating picture boxes and checkboxes.Anyways It seems I have to research for more understanding the mechanics before giving a shot to make this issue done. Thanks for your attention

Comment: Do you know if I am able to use WPF and use Data Binding tools? If it is doable how may I achieve it?